# How to use body_class to change css according to page hierarchy

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

Trying to set up various css rules based on my Wordpress page hierarchy, and found out that wordpress can auto-generate these rules using [body_class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class#Page) but I have absolutely no idea how to implement it. can someone explain it to me step-by-step? (Aka, what do i need to put in the functions.php, what do i need to put in the css file)?

Basically, I want to change the header text background, depending on what the parent page is.
Eg:

- .../news, and all its subpages (...news/newsletter-signup, news/submit, etc) would be blue
- .../community, and all its subpages (...community/resources/supermarkets, ...community/how-to/pay-utilities, etc) would be purple.
- .../events, and all its subpages would be orange.

TIA!

Comment: Do you have a link to your site? It makes it easier to explain in details.

Comment: The site isn't online yet, im running it on WAMP until I have it all set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, we have standart page, like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- HEAD CONTENT -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="post">
        <h1>Title of post</h1>
        <p>Text or another content of post</p>
      </div>
      <div class="post">
        <h1>Title of post</h1>
        <p>Text or another content of post</p>
      </div>
      <div class="post">
        <h1>Title of post</h1>
        <p>Text or another content of post</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, we can use body_class() function to customize view for different category types.

First: put body_class() function into body tag

```
<body <? body_class(); ?>>
```

Second: write classes for each category

```
body.home .post, body.news .post, body.blog .post {
  width: 640px;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

body.portfolio .post, body.work .post, body.projects .post {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  float: left;

}
```

Now all posts on the main page, in the blog and in the category of news are displayed line by line.

All publications in the portfolio section and category projects are displayed in three columns.

Example for home, news and blog:

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
}
.container {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 660px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.post {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 240px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}
body.home .post,
body.news .post,
body.blog .post {
  width: 640px;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
body.portfolio .post,
body.work .post,
body.projects .post {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!-- HEAD CONTENT -->
</head>

<body class="home">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="post">
      <h1>Title of post</h1>
      <p>Text or another content of post</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <h1>Title of post</h1>
      <p>Text or another content of post</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <h1>Title of post</h1>
      <p>Text or another content of post</p>
    </div>
    <br clear="all">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Example for works, projects and portfolio:

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
}
.container {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 660px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.post {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 240px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}
body.home .post,
body.news .post,
body.blog .post {
  width: 640px;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
body.portfolio .post,
body.work .post,
body.projects .post {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!-- HEAD CONTENT -->
</head>

<body class="work">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="post">
      <h1>Title of post</h1>
      <p>Text or another content of post</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <h1>Title of post</h1>
      <p>Text or another content of post</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <h1>Title of post</h1>
      <p>Text or another content of post</p>
    </div>
    <br clear="all">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: And if I wanted it to be based on page parent, not on post type or category- How would I go about doing that? What would i put in the css file?

Answer (score 0):

in your header.php file change this `<body>` to `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`